# Image inside <li> tag

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have a question about floating elements inside of `<li>` tag.

I have following markup

```
<li>
<img src="concept-truck.jpg" alt="2013 Toyota Tacoma" id="itemImg" style="float:left">
<p>2013 Toyota Tacoma</p>
<p>Price : 450000$</p>
<p>Year : 2013</p>
<p><a href="/item/index/63">more</a></p>            
</li>
```

In FF, IE works fine, but in Chrome list numeration floats image too.
How to fix it? Thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I would rewrite your example like this:

```
<li>
    <div style="float: left;">
        <img src="concept-truck.jpg" alt="2013 Toyota Tacoma" id="itemImg">
    </div>
    <div style="float: left;">
        <p>2013 Toyota Tacoma</p>
        <p>Price : 450000$</p>
        <p>Year : 2013</p>
        <p><a href="/item/index/63">more</a></p>
    </div>
    <div style="float: none; clear: both;"></div>
</li>
```

This is written with inline-style CSS attributes, which I usually tend to avoid, but as in your example, I wrote it like you did - inline.

Comment: That's not correct way