# Add arrow (images) between inline list items using css

Tags: html, css

I have the following unordered list:

```
<ul>
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li>4</li>
</ul>
```

which when rendered appears inline as follows:

1   2   3   4

I have an image of a left-to-right arrow (arrow.gif) which I'd like to appear (using CSS) between each subsequent numbers so that the list renders like this:

1 ---> 2 ---> 3 ---> 4

Can this be done using just CSS?

Thank so much!

Comment: have you tried to include the image within the <li>. For example, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17921949/image-inside-li-tag

Comment: Have you tried any CSS yet? Maybe like a background image?

Answer (score 3):

I would do :

```
li {display:inline-block;
}
li + li:before {
content:url(arrow.gif);
vertical-align:middle;
/* extra make up , whatever*/
display:inline-block;
padding:0 0.25em;
}
```

first `li` has no arrow, then any others will show an arrow on its `left` side (if document direction is `ltr` , opposite otherwise).

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Ybr9W/1/)**

---

**To see arrows standing outside**, you can set them in absolute position or use a negative text-indent width , at least , width of the arrow :

**[DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/Ybr9W/5/)**

basic html can be alike :

```
li +li:before {
    display:inline-block;
    content:url('http://mywaive.com/templates/friend5/images/arrow.gif');
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-indent:-35px;
}
li {
    display:inline-block;
    border:solid;
    margin-left: 40px;
}
```

Comment: here an example using the li +li technique to draw pipes : http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/bInJg

Comment: Thanks very much for the help, this method looks very encouraging!

Comment: This answer is very close to solving this for me. The only problem now is that I have a border around each li and when the arrow is added it draws the border around the arrow AND the list item. Is there a way, just using css and not javascript, so that the border only goes around the actual list item and not the arrow as well.  Here is a jsfiddle of the current situtation: http://jsfiddle.net/Ybr9W/4/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the arrow image is 30px wide:

`ul li:first-of-type {padding:0;background:transparent;}
ul li {float:left;display:inline;padding-left:30px;background:url('images/arrow.gif') no-repeat 0 0;}`

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help.  I will give this a try as well.

Answer (score 0):

It's tough to make something perfect without seeing your image or current CSS, but you can do something like below. You'll have to adjust the sizing but this should be a good base for you to work with.

```
li {
    display:inline-block;
    background-image:url('arrow.gif');
    background-position:center;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    width:100px;
    height:50px;
    background-size:contain;
}
```

Here is a fiddle showing it off: http://jsfiddle.net/Ybr9W/

Like I said, it's not perfect, but it's easy to adjust.

Of course, the other option is to just use an `img` tag inside of the `li` elements...

Comment: Add the `li:not(:first-child)` or `li:not(:last-child)` selector to prevent the first (or last) child from rendering the image.

Comment: Thanks for the help, it's greatly appreciated that you would take the time!